# Laravel Response::download() without exposing download path

Tags: laravel-4, download, laravel-routing

I am a bit confused with Response::download() in Laravel 4.2

I would like to trigger a download of a ZIP archive without exposing the actual public path of the file..

This is the error I am getting when accessing the route

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

My ROUTE is written like this:

```
/*
/ Download Package (GET)
*/
Route::get('/download-packages/{$package}', array(
    'as'    => 'download-package',
    'uses'  => 'DownloadController@getPackageDownload'
));
```

In the Controller getPackageDownload function is written like this:

```
public function getPackageDownload( $package ){

    $file = public_path() . "/downloads/packages/" . $package . ".zip" ;
    $name = $package . ".zip";

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
    );

    return Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
}
```

My View button code:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('download-package',[$package->package]) }}" target="_blank">Download</a></div>
```

The Download link generated in the view is something like this

```
http://app.dev/laravel/public/download-packages/package-name
```

It is different from the actual public location of the ZIP file but that is desired and my understanding is that the response should be triggered in the getPackageDownload function.

Answer (score 1):

So, after walking away from the code and coming back to it with refreshed eyes it turns out I simply had a routing error,, routing parameter $package should not have "$" in front of it..

```
/*
/ Download Package (GET)
*/
Route::get('/download-packages/{package}', array(
    'as'    => 'download-package',
    'uses'  => 'DownloadController@getPackageDownload'
));
```